# Odoo Qweb check for contact title

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I am currently working on my first Odoo (v8) template and want to check if a contact person has a specific title.
What currently works is:

```
Sehr geehrter <span t-field="o.partner_id.title"></span> <span t-field="o.partner_id.name"></span>
```

This outputs:

```
Sehr geehrter Herr Klaus Koffer
```

As you can see I use the german translation of the system.

**My question is:** How can I check for "Mister" and "Miss"? The following example does not work. Is there a way to get the internav values as they are obviously not "Mister".

```
<p t-if="o.partner_id.title == 'Mister'">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer our [blog](http://blog.emiprotechnologies.com/create-qweb-report-odoo/) to know about qweb.

Just try it in your code.

```
t-if="o.partner_id.title.name == 'Mister'"
```

Because `o.partner_id.title` gives an object of `res.partner.title` model.

So, you have to user `o.partner_id.title.name`. that's it.

Comment: There is nothing about t-if or partner_id.title

Comment: About qweb template engine you will get another link in blog, where you can see how to put the condition in qweb.

Comment: I have changed my answer please have a look on it.

Answer (score -1):

Just you can check the condition using `<t> </t>` Tag for add the condition in Qweb View.

Better way u should use the `<t>` Tag insted of `<p>` Tag

some thing like this

```
<t t-if="o.partner_id.title == 'Mister'">
    Your login will add hear for Mister title
</t>
```

I hope this should helpful for you ..)